# how to insert BigInteger value in the oracle database

Tags: java, oracle

i m trying to insert a BigInteger value in the oracle database.i m trying like this:

```
BigInteger a=new BigInteger("4280972057205720579205792572075927209857");
String str=new String(a.toByteArray());
```

now in the database :

```
 PerparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into database values(?)");
 pstmt.setString(1,str);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

if i m using `str="hello"` then it is working fine.but if i m using `str=new String(a.toByteArray())`   then nothing(null) is inserted in the database.why it is so.please explain and also suggest some method to do so.

Comment: my datatype of the column in the database is varchar2(4000).

Comment: hello guys....i used toString method and it is working.but i want to know why i was not able to insert using my previous approach.is there any type compatiblity issue between java String and oracle varchar2.

Comment: The String you created probably contains some illegal byte values. Try to print it (with _System.out.println_ or similar) before calling the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for [`BigInteger.toByteArray()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()):

> Returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of this BigInteger. The byte array will be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

This has nothing to do with representing it in Decimal!  You want to use `BigInteger.toString()` to get the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

```
String str=a.toString();
```